# Why does happen "request entity too large" error?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-413

**"nginx 413 request entity too large"**

I didn`t solve this problem.

Please let me know this problem if you know this. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the web server that is running a website that you are trying to access decides that the HTTP data stream that your web browser is sending to it is too large (in this context, “too large” means that the data stream has way too many bytes), it will not cope with it and issue error 413.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem you should increase the maximum size of the client request body using client_max_body_size directive.

You can follow following steps:

1. open nginx.conf file

in ubuntu:

```
vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

2. add line. X can be big enough to allow large files.For example 20M

   client_max_body_size XM;
3. Reload nginx.
   in ubuntu

   /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload